# mako template variable division

Tags: python, html, mako

I am using mako for creating html templates.

I my template, I have the following code:

```
% for s in query['sandboxes']:
% for node in s['nodes']:

<table>
<tr>

<td>${node['node_name']}</td>
<td>${node['slowcall_count']}) / ${s['slowcall_count']}</td>

</tr>    
</table>

% endfor
% endfor
```

The loop and display are working, but it displays "30 / 100" instead of the actual division result.

After searching, I saw this [Using from __future__ import in Mako template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537213/using-from-future-import-in-mako-template)

and then tried this code:

```
<td>
<%! 
float(${node['slowcall_count']}) / float(${s['slowcall_count']}) 
%>
```

but it gives me a syntax error. The follwoing doesn't give any error, but it doesn't display anything either:

```
<td>
<%! 
float(1) / float(2)
%>
```

Is there a way to make my division work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work between the td tags:

```
${float(node['slowcall_count']) / float(s['slowcall_count']) }
```

An expression can occur inside the ${}. As explained here:

http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#expression-substitution

Comment: Marvelous! I tried this before, but inside the <%! %>, and it did not work. This line plain and simple works. Thank you.